# How to get network adapter subnet mask in C#?

Tags: c#, windows, ethernet

In Windows I can configure the IP address and subnet mask of a network adapter

How can I query this subnet mask from a C# application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer myself. Turns out the subnet mask can be obtained via this property:

```
UnicastIPAddressInformation.IPv4Mask
```